# Systemd service creation of Prometheus and Node Exporter

Tags: systemd, init-script

I am trying to create services for both Prometheus and Node Exporter.

Both .service files have nearly identical content.

```
    #!/bin/sh -
    # /etc/systemd/system/node_exporter.service
    [Unit]
    Description=Node Exporter

    [Service]
    User=prometheus
    RemainAfterExit=true
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/node_exporter
```

My issue is I cannot start the service. I get the following error

```
    ● node_exporter.service - Node Exporter
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/node_exporter.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-01-30 16:00:31 MST; 7min ago
Process: 18693 ExecStart=/usr/bin/node_exporter (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Main PID: 18693 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

I have tried changing the user, verifying the path is correct, among many many other iterations. I for the life of me cannot get this to work after hours of tweaking, google, and backtracking. There are guides for Upstart, but I need this to work on 16.04 without Upstart as a dependency.

Comment: here's an example of [working service file](https://github.com/lest/prometheus-rpm/blob/master/node_exporter/node_exporter.service)

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem like this...

**Node exporter:**

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/node_exporter'
```

**Mysql_exporter:**

```
=/bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/mysqld_exporter \
 --config.my-cnf /etc/.mysqld_exporter.cnf \
 --collect.global_status \
 --collect.info_schema.innodb_metrics \
 --collect.auto_increment.columns \
 --collect.info_schema.processlist \
 --collect.binlog_size \
 --collect.info_schema.tablestats \
 --collect.global_variables \
 --collect.info_schema.query_response_time \
 --collect.info_schema.userstats \
 --collect.info_schema.tables \
 --collect.perf_schema.tablelocks \
 --collect.perf_schema.file_events \
 --collect.perf_schema.eventswaits \
 --collect.perf_schema.indexiowaits \
 --collect.perf_schema.tableiowaits \
 --collect.slave_status \
 --web.listen-address=0.0.0.0:9104'
```

**Here is the complete command:**

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/mysql_exporter.service
```

**Content for `mysql_exporter.service`:**

```
 [Unit]
 Description=Prometheus MySQL Exporter
 After=network.target

 [Service]
 Type=simple
 Restart=always
 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/mysqld_exporter \
 --config.my-cnf /etc/.mysqld_exporter.cnf \
 --collect.global_status \
 --collect.info_schema.innodb_metrics \
 --collect.auto_increment.columns \
 --collect.info_schema.processlist \
 --collect.binlog_size \
 --collect.info_schema.tablestats \
 --collect.global_variables \
 --collect.info_schema.query_response_time \
 --collect.info_schema.userstats \
 --collect.info_schema.tables \
 --collect.perf_schema.tablelocks \
 --collect.perf_schema.file_events \
 --collect.perf_schema.eventswaits \
 --collect.perf_schema.indexiowaits \
 --collect.perf_schema.tableiowaits \
 --collect.slave_status \
 --web.listen-address=0.0.0.0:9104'
 
 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Node exporter:**

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/node_exporter.service
```

**Content for `node_exporter`:**

```
 [Unit]
 Description=Prometheus Node Exporter
 After=network.target
 User=prometheus
 Group=prometheus

 [Service]
 Type=simple
 Restart=always
 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/node_exporter'

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Very thanks for your answer. But why?`/usr/local/bin/node_exporter` can be executed successfully manually.

Comment: The same worked for me. I would like to understand why if someone can kindly help

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the path node_exporter is not correct.

```
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/node_exporter
```

I have another path to it on Ubuntu 16.04

```
~# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS \n \l

~# which node_exporter
/usr/sbin/node_exporter
```

If it's not the root of the issue, check your `/var/log/syslog`. It must show the reason of the failure, something similar to:

```
Oct 20 12:30:30 prom systemd[8848]: node_exporter.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/node_exporter: No such file or directory
Oct 20 12:30:30 prom systemd[1]: node_exporter.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Oct 20 12:30:30 prom systemd[1]: node_exporter.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 20 12:30:30 prom systemd[1]: node_exporter.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 20 12:30:30 prom systemd[1]: node_exporter.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 20 12:30:30 prom systemd[1]: Stopped Prometheus exporter for machine metrics, written in Go with pluggable metric collectors..
Oct 20 12:30:30 prom systemd[1]: Started Prometheus exporter for machine metrics, written in Go with pluggable metric collectors..
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to launch the command you're passing to `ExecStart` manually to verify whether it runs.

I got the 203 error as well and apparently it was due to downloading/using the binary for the wrong platform. I was using "Darwin" instead of "Linux".

```
  Process: 20340 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node_exporter (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

$ ls -lah /usr/local/bin/node_exporter
-rwxr-xr-x 1 node_exporter node_exporter 12M Jan 16 16:36 /usr/local/bin/node_exporter
$ /usr/local/bin/node_exporter
-bash: /usr/local/bin/node_exporter: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `/etc/systemd/system/node_exporter.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Node Exporter
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=node_exporter
Group=node_exporter
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node_exporter --collector.nfs --collector.nfsd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and make sure the `node_exporter` binary in placed in an expected path.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error. Solved as @Saex.

Reason for getting this error is that I have downloaded the wrong package `node_exporter-1.2.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz` instead of `node_exporter-1.2.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz`

```
    node_exporter.service - Node Exporter
         Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/node_exporter.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
         Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-08-18 11:22:44 UTC; 17s ago
       Main PID: 3830 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Aug 18 11:22:44 ip-10-0-101-80 systemd[1]: Started Node Exporter.
Aug 18 11:22:44 ip-10-0-101-80 systemd[3830]: node_exporter.service: Failed to execute command: Exec format error
Aug 18 11:22:44 ip-10-0-101-80 systemd[3830]: node_exporter.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/node_exporter/node_exporter: Exec>
Aug 18 11:22:44 ip-10-0-101-80 systemd[1]: node_exporter.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 18 11:22:44 ip-10-0-101-80 systemd[1]: node_exporter.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```